# how to run automation task in different group using fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I want to run different command on the different pc group.
my fabric file like following:

```
env.hosts = ['125.221.225.31','125.221.225.36','125.221.225.33','125.221.225.34','125.221.225.35']
env.roledefs = {
    'master':['125.221.225.31'],
    'slave':['125.221.225.33','125.221.225.34','125.221.225.35','125.221.225.36']}

@roles('master')
def get_last_hosts():
    with cd('/etc'):
        get('hosts','/tmp/hosts')

@roles('slave')
def upload_hosts():
    with lcd('/tmp'):
        put('hosts','/etc/hosts',use_sudo=True)

def update_hosts():
    get_last_hosts()
    upload_hosts()
```

I can run:

```
fab get_last_hosts,
```

and then run:

```
fab upload_hosts
```

I want to merge these steps to one step, so to say:

update_hosts

but that won't work, it will run `update_hosts` on every pc in the env.hosts, that's not what I desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around this by using the [execute](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/usage/execution.html#intelligently-executing-tasks-with-execute) command. In something like this:

```
def update_hosts():
    execute(get_last_hosts)
    execute(upload_hosts)
```